# Stateful Retry Advice does not resubmit message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are using Spring Integration + JMS + ActiveMQ to exchange messages between microservices using [Virtual Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html).

Here is our configuration for the inbound messages:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory
@Autowired
lateinit var messageConverter: MessageConverter


@Bean("file-uploaded.inbound")
fun inboundChannel() = MessageChannels.queue().get()

@Bean("file-uploaded.inbound.flow")
fun inboundFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    Jms.container(connectionFactory, 
                                  "Consumer.appId.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded")
                        .pubSubDomain(false).get()
                ).jmsMessageConverter(messageConverter)
            ).channel(inboundChannel()).get()
}
```

and here is our retry advice (fairly default, except for the retry state generator):

```
@Bean
fun requestHandlerRetryAdvice(): RequestHandlerRetryAdvice {
    return RequestHandlerRetryAdvice().apply {
        setRetryStateGenerator(SpelExpressionRetryStateGenerator("headers[\"jms_messageId\"]"))
        setRecoveryCallback(ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer())
    }
}
```

and message handler:

```
@MessageEndpoint
class FileUploadedEventListener() {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "file-uploaded.inbound", adviceChain = ["requestHandlerRetryAdvice"])
    fun handleFileUploadedEvent(fileUploadedEvent: FileUploadedEvent) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass.name).info("Received event: $fileUploadedEvent")
        throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Basically the reply advice is not putting the message back on the queue as it is supposed to (as per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#retry-config)) and it is sending an error message on the 'errorChannel' after the first try.

Has anyone experienced the same problem using Virtual Topics?
Or are we just missing something in the configuration?

Thanks!

**Update** here below the debug logging:

```
2018-09-19 15:40:07.877 DEBUG .i.j.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener : converted JMS Message [ActiveMQBytesMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, originalDestination = topic://VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1, destination = queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1537368007815, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1537368007821, brokerOutTime = 1537368007822, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@732fdf26, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@6ca08492, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, spanParentSpanId=4770babc94e7d760, _type=FileUploadedEvent, spanSampled=0}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = java.io.DataInputStream@33c0baa3 }] to integration Message payload [FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1)]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.879 DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'file-uploaded.inbound.flow.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, spanParentSpanId=4770babc94e7d760, jms_redelivered=false, jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, id=266d356e-dc90-cb33-8818-40a3cf718125, priority=4, spanSampled=0, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, timestamp=1537368007879}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.882 DEBUG o.s.integration.handler.BridgeHandler    : file-uploaded.inbound.flow.org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, X-B3-ParentSpanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, spanParentSpanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[04c0bd5a812ee159], spanParentSpanId=[0c31247dd4ed71eb], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=33d89f7b-dbf8-b381-add7-549d875dd914, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, timestamp=1537368007881}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.883 DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : preSend on channel 'file-uploaded.inbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, X-B3-ParentSpanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, spanParentSpanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[04c0bd5a812ee159], spanParentSpanId=[0c31247dd4ed71eb], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=33d89f7b-dbf8-b381-add7-549d875dd914, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, timestamp=1537368007881}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.884 DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'file-uploaded.inbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, X-B3-ParentSpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=49b4d98b393a623e, spanParentSpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanParentSpanId=[04c0bd5a812ee159], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[04c0bd5a812ee159], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=70e86708-b383-ce4a-61f5-36a69ecadfeb, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, timestamp=1537368007883}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.884 DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : postReceive on channel 'file-uploaded.inbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, X-B3-ParentSpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=49b4d98b393a623e, spanParentSpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanParentSpanId=[04c0bd5a812ee159], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[04c0bd5a812ee159], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=70e86708-b383-ce4a-61f5-36a69ecadfeb, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, timestamp=1537368007883}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.884 DEBUG o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@62a15309] (fileUploadedEventListener.handleFileUploadedEvent.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanParentSpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.884 DEBUG o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'file-uploaded.inbound.flow.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, X-B3-ParentSpanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, spanParentSpanId=0c31247dd4ed71eb, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanParentSpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=04c0bd5a812ee159, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=33d89f7b-dbf8-b381-add7-549d875dd914, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1, timestamp=1537368007881}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.888 DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2018-09-19 15:40:07.901  INFO c.b.p.a.a.e.FileUploadedEventListener    : Received file uploaded event GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanParentSpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.902 DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2018-09-19 15:40:07.902 DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Rethrow in retry for policy: count=1
2018-09-19 15:40:07.904 DEBUG o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanParentSpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}], headers={id=631dd6f9-0e84-15c7-c953-48d732c25270, timestamp=1537368007904}] for original GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, X-B3-ParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanParentSpanId=[49b4d98b393a623e], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=88313bfb-a45d-c9ff-268f-5c2f50e03156, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.904 DEBUG o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@484a98b8] (fileUploadedEventListener.handleError.serviceActivator.handler) received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], spanParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}], headers={X-B3-ParentSpanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=69a058ce-deed-f3e2-eb20-d4e874171ba6, X-B3-SpanId=b72c67f61de7c366, timestamp=1537368007904}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.905 DEBUG o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@484a98b8] (fileUploadedEventListener.handleError.serviceActivator.handler)' produced no reply for request Message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], spanParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}], headers={X-B3-ParentSpanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=69a058ce-deed-f3e2-eb20-d4e874171ba6, X-B3-SpanId=b72c67f61de7c366, timestamp=1537368007904}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.905 DEBUG o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], spanParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}], headers={X-B3-ParentSpanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=69a058ce-deed-f3e2-eb20-d4e874171ba6, X-B3-SpanId=b72c67f61de7c366, timestamp=1537368007904}]
2018-09-19 15:40:07.906 ERROR o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], spanParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:182)
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at FileUploadedEventListener.handleFileUploadedEvent(FileUploadedEventListener.kt:35)
    at FileUploadedEventListener$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eb75a593.invoke(<generated>)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:574)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:468)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:104)
    ... 29 more

2018-09-19 15:40:07.907 DEBUG o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FileUploadedEvent(assetId=c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, objectKey=account-id/c9c73263-e05c-4cb0-bf7b-ea2d3b934c13, bucketName=platform-asset-storage-dev, accountId=account-id, fileName=unknown, userId=1), headers={jms_destination=queue://Consumer.dev-platform-asset-previews.VirtualTopic.file-uploaded, _type=FileUploadedEvent, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1537368007815, spanTraceId=4770babc94e7d760, spanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, spanParentSpanId=49b4d98b393a623e, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], spanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], spanParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[4770babc94e7d760], X-B3-SpanId=[b72c67f61de7c366], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[7f9b16d7f7d5b347], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, id=4c6d131e-448e-9863-f84b-7a4a8e563b09, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:Marcos-MBP.intranet-57777-1537280015474-1:71:1:1:1}], headers={X-B3-ParentSpanId=7f9b16d7f7d5b347, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=4770babc94e7d760, id=69a058ce-deed-f3e2-eb20-d4e874171ba6, X-B3-SpanId=b72c67f61de7c366, timestamp=1537368007904}]
```

Comment: The advice doesn't "put the message back on the queue", it simply re-throws the exception (until retries are exhausted); the listener container in the JMS adapter rolls back the transaction, which puts the message back on the queue. Turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for that @GaryRussell, so I'm guessing that the JMS adapter is not rolling back the transaction then. I have already turned DEBUG logging on but I can only see that it is sending an error to the 'errorChannel' after the first try.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I have added our debug logging, the only difference that I can spot is that the example in the docs has `failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive` warnings coming from `MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive()` which are missing from our logging.
Does it mean it's following a different path in sending the message to the service activator?

Comment: See my answer - you can't use a `QueueChannel` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fun inboundChannel() = MessageChannels.queue().get()`

It's because you are using a `QueueChannel` - you need `DirectChannel` if you want the exception to be thrown back to inbound channel adapter so the message will be requeued.

With a queue channel, the poller will simply send the exception to the error channel.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that was it!